# Python: How can I parse this list?

Tags: python, list, parsing

I am writing a script to grab stock info using an API. I have stored some API data in a variable called "ids" that I would like to loop through. When trying to loop using my code, it seems to output each character rather than each item in the list. How can I correctly parse this list?

BTW, I noticed that the list has an additional set of square brackets surrounding it. Not sure if this has anything to do with it. I am new to python and am not exactly sure what type of data I am dealing with.

```
print(ids)
```

> ```
> [["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e", "943c5009-a0bb-4665-8cf4-a95dab5874e4"], ["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e", "943c5009-a0bb-4665-8cf4-a95dab5874e4"], ["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e", "41eac3c6-f7f7-4c4a-b696-ab9d1b913981"], ["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e"], ["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e"], ["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e"], ["943c5009-a0bb-4665-8cf4-a95dab5874e4", "450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e"], ["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e", "943c5009-a0bb-4665-8cf4-a95dab5874e4"], ["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e", "943c5009-a0bb-4665-8cf4-a95dab5874e4"], ["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e"]]
> ```

```
for id in ids:
    print(id)
```

> [

> [

> "

> 4

> 5

> 0

> ...etc.

Comment: Looks like you have a string not a list of lists.

Comment: It works perfectly fine in my case

Comment: I don't know Kyle, the way you explained it, it should work. Please post your whole code so we can help you better.

Comment: looks like you get a json response from the API which is a string and which you should decode to actual python list by using `json` python module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not positive I have the best answer here. I noticed that running the following code works. I changed the variable names here. `tempIDS` is the same variable as `ids` was. I'm not sure if this is the best way, but it seems to function:

```
tempIDS = r.stocks.get_news("AAPL","related_instruments")
base = "https://api.robinhood.com/instruments/"
global stockName
for tempID in tempIDS:
    for sID in tempID:
        print(sID)
        stockName = r.stocks.get_name_by_url(base+sID)
```

Here is the full code so far to get a better context. I know this probably could use a lot of improvements:

```
import os
import json
import robin_stocks as r
#API Documentation: http://www.robin-stocks.com/en/latest/functions.html

#Login later for live trades
login = r.login('','')

global SYMBOL

def grabLatest(SYMBOL):
    global fundamentals,latestPrice,news,relatedInstruments,ids
    fundamentals = r.stocks.get_fundamentals(SYMBOL)
    latestPrice = r.stocks.get_latest_price(SYMBOL, includeExtendedHours=True)
    news = r.stocks.get_news(SYMBOL,"preview_text")
    tempIDS = r.stocks.get_news(SYMBOL,"related_instruments")
    
def sentimentAnalysis():
    global x
    global negativeScore
    global positiveScore
    global controversy 
    x = 0
    negativeScore = 0
    positiveScore = 0
    controversy = 0
    
    for i in news:
        custom_tweet = news[x]
        custom_tokens = remove_noise(word_tokenize(custom_tweet))
        sentiment = classifier.classify(dict([token, True] for token in custom_tokens))
        print(sentiment)
        print(custom_tweet)
        print("")
        x+=1
        if (sentiment is "Negative"):
            negativeScore -= 1
        if (sentiment is "Positive"):
            positiveScore += 1
    
    controversy = positiveScore - negativeScore
    
def parseRelated(SYMBOL):
    tempIDS = r.stocks.get_news(SYMBOL,"related_instruments")
    base = "https://api.robinhood.com/instruments/"
    global stockName
    global relatedStocks
    relatedStocks=[]
    for tempID in tempIDS:
        for sID in tempID:
            print(sID)
            relatedStocks.append(sID)
    
    for stock in relatedStocks:
        stockName = r.stocks.get_name_by_url(base+sID)
        print(stockName)
    
grabLatest("TSLA")
#parseRelated("TSLA")
print('FUNDAMENTALS:')
print(fundamentals[0])
print('')
print('LATEST PRICE:')
print(latestPrice)
print('')
sentimentAnalysis()
print("News sentiment analysis")     
print("Positive Score: ",positiveScore)
print("Negative Score: ",negativeScore)
print("Controversy: ",controversy)
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Chris mentioned it seems that you are iterating over a string.

Let

```
id_list = '[["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e", "943c5009-a0bb-4665-8cf4-a95dab5874e4"], ["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e", "943c5009-a0bb-4665-8cf4-a95dab5874e4"], ["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e", "41eac3c6-f7f7-4c4a-b696-ab9d1b913981"], ["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e"], ["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e"], ["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e"], ["943c5009-a0bb-4665-8cf4-a95dab5874e4", "450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e"], ["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e", "943c5009-a0bb-4665-8cf4-a95dab5874e4"], ["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e", "943c5009-a0bb-4665-8cf4-a95dab5874e4"], ["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e"]]'
```

When you print it you receive:

```
print(id_list)
>>> [["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e", "943c5009-a0bb-4665-8cf4-a95dab5874e4"], ["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e", "943c5009-a0bb-4665-8cf4-a95dab5874e4"], ["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e", "41eac3c6-f7f7-4c4a-b696-ab9d1b913981"], ["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e"], ["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e"], ["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e"], ["943c5009-a0bb-4665-8cf4-a95dab5874e4", "450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e"], ["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e", "943c5009-a0bb-4665-8cf4-a95dab5874e4"], ["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e", "943c5009-a0bb-4665-8cf4-a95dab5874e4"], ["450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e"]]
```

If you use the json module to parse your data you can do the following:

```
import json
for ids in json.loads(id_list):
    for id_ in ids:
        print(id_)

>>> 450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e
>>> 943c5009-a0bb-4665-8cf4-a95dab5874e4
>>> 450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e
>>> 943c5009-a0bb-4665-8cf4-a95dab5874e4
>>> 450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e
>>> 41eac3c6-f7f7-4c4a-b696-ab9d1b913981
>>> 450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e
>>> 450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e
>>> 450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e
>>> 943c5009-a0bb-4665-8cf4-a95dab5874e4
>>> 450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e
>>> 450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e
>>> 943c5009-a0bb-4665-8cf4-a95dab5874e4
>>> 450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e
>>> 943c5009-a0bb-4665-8cf4-a95dab5874e4
>>> 450dfc6d-5510-4d40-abfb-f633b7d9be3e
```

PS: Don't use built-ins for variable names! https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id

EDIT:
The function `robin_stocks.helper.request_get` appears to have a parameter `jsonify_data`. When you use it, you should get the data in the format that you need

Comment: Thanks Boris, I found that I am receiving a JSON response. I think it is a list of strings? I was not quite able to use the code with json.loads, but it got me on the right track. Here is the response I received:

`raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '`

BTW, thanks for the recommendation on built-in variable names. I had a hunch I might have been stepping on some toes.

Comment: Can you provide us with some more detail about the response that you receive? Post the API for example or an output of the result. The information that you have in your question is rather scarce

Comment: Sure, sorry about that. This is the API I am using: http://www.robin-stocks.com/en/latest/functions.html
I will also edit to include my full code in the answer I posted below.